# Console eventhandling doesn`t work like supposed c++

Tags: c++, windows, console, event-handling

I have the problem that the defined function `consoleHandler()` gets called with an unexpected value for the `DWORD CEvent` parameter, so that the `switch` statement never matches the defined cases, only `default` gets called.

`CEvent` is always some strange random number. If I print out `CRTL_CLOSE_EVENT` I get a 2. `CEvent` is never 2, even if I close the window with the mouse.

What is happening? Is there some problem with the typecast?

```
class Runner {

    bool isRunning = false;

public:

    void reevoke(){
        char p[] = "path to exe";
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

        ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

        CreateProcess(p ,   // the path
                      NULL,        // Command line
                      NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
                      NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
                      FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
                      0,              // No creation flags
                      NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
                      NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
                      &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                      &pi             // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure (removed extra parentheses)
        );
    }

    BOOL WINAPI ConsoleHandler(DWORD CEvent)
    {
        cout << CEvent << " | " <<  CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT <<endl;

        switch(CEvent)
        {
            /*case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
                MessageBox(NULL,
                           "CTRL+BREAK received!","CEvent",MB_OK);
                cout << "closed bbbb"<<endl;
                this->reevoke();
                break;*/

            case CTRL_C_EVENT:
                this->reevoke();
                return TRUE;

            case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
                Beep(600, 200);
                printf("Ctrl-Close event\n\n");
                return TRUE;

            default:
                 cout << "Event was: " << CEvent  <<endl;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    ~Runner()
    {
        if(GetKeyState('Q') & 0x8000){
            cout << "q pressed" << endl;
        }
        else{
            if(SetConsoleCtrlHandler(
                (PHANDLER_ROUTINE)&ConsoleHandler, // handler function
                TRUE // add or remove handler
            ) == FALSE){
                cout << "could not set Handler" << endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "Handler Set" << endl;
                Sleep(1000);
            }

            while (1) {}

            cout << "constructor called" << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world! I am unstoppable" << endl;
    Runner r;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `this->reevoke();` -- This is highly suspicious.  Are you attempting to use a non-static class member function as a callback?  If you are, you can't do that.  Remove the cast here: `(PHANDLER_ROUTINE)&ConsoleHandler` -- once you do that, what compiler error do you get?

Comment: main.cpp|81|error: cannot convert 'Runner::ConsoleHandler' from type 'BOOL (Runner::)(DWORD) {aka int (Runner::)(long unsigned int)}' to type 'PHANDLER_ROUTINE {aka int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(long unsigned int)}'|

Comment: Well, that settles it.  You basically told the compiler to "shut up, I know what I'm doing" when you applied the C-style cast.  The compiler is telling you that the functions are not the same -- once you applied the cast, then all bets are off as to what the code will produce (see the answer by RemyLebeau).  A non-static member function is not the same as an "ordinary" free function.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ConsoleHandler()` is a **non-static** class method.  It must be called on an object instance of `Runner`.

Which means, you *can't* use it as an Win32 API callback. It has a hidden `this` parameter, which the API doesn't know about, and so can't pass the `Runner` object address to.

Your typecast to force `ConsoleHandler()` as a callback is invoking *undefined behavior*, which is why the `CEvent` parameter is not receiving the correct values.  It is receiving its value from the wrong memory location.

There is a valid reason why this code will fail to compile if you drop the typecast.  Only free-standing functions, and **static** class methods, can be used as Win32 API callbacks.  Do not use typecasts to silence compiler errors. Fix the errors instead.

Try this instead:

```
class Runner {
public:
    static void reevoke(){
        char p[] = "path to exe";
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

        ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

        if (CreateProcess(p,              // the path
                          NULL,           // Command line
                          NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
                          NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
                          FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
                          0,              // No creation flags
                          NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
                          NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
                          &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                          &pi             // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure (removed extra parentheses)
            ))
        {
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        }
    }

    static BOOL WINAPI ConsoleHandler(DWORD CEvent)
    {
        cout << CEvent << " | " <<  CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT << endl;

        switch (CEvent)
        {
            case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
                Beep(600, 200);
                MessageBox(NULL,
                           "CTRL+BREAK received!",
                           "CEvent",
                           MB_OK);
                cout << "closed bbbb" << endl;
                reevoke();
                break;

            case CTRL_C_EVENT:
                reevoke();
                return TRUE;

            default:
                 cout << "Event was: " << CEvent << endl;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    ~Runner()
    {
        cout << "destructor called" << endl;
        if (GetKeyState('Q') & 0x8000){
            cout << "q pressed" << endl;
        }
        else if (SetConsoleCtrlHandler(&ConsoleHandler, TRUE) == FALSE){
            cout << "could not set Handler" << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Handler Set" << endl;
            Sleep(1000);

            while (1) {}
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world! I am unstoppable" << endl;
    Runner r;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thx that worked. made ConsoleHandler(DWORD CEvent) static and used it like this Runner::ConsoleHandler(DWORD CEvent)